# Wildfly 26.1.2.Final: ModuleNotFoundException

Tags: java, gradle, wildfly, elytron, galleon

We want to use Wildfly's `elytron-tool` utility for managing a keystore. We dynamically provision Wildfly `26.1.2.Final` with the following commands in our `gradle.properties`:

```
galleonVersion = 5.0.5.Final
wildflyVersion = 26.1.2.Final
wildflyLayers = cdi,jaxrs,microprofile-config,logging,datasources,mail,h2-datasource,core-management,web-console,core-toolstwild
```

(I have also tried adding `elytron` and `elytron-tool` to the wildFlyLayers variable above, without success as you will find out.)

Unfortunately, when running either `elytron-tool.sh` or `elytron-tool.bat`, we get a `ModuleNotFoundException` for `elytron-tool`:

```bash
org.jboss.modules.ModuleNotFoundException: org.wildfly.security.elytron-tool
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoader.loadModule(ModuleLoader.java:301)
at org.jboss.modules.Main.main(Main.java:358)
```

From the [issue tracker](https://issues.redhat.com/browse/WFLY-18321) I denote a comment that says that this issue has been fixed in Wildfly 27. We were wondering if this issue is in any way solvable in Wildfly 26, since we would prefer to not upgrade our WildFly version at this time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to access and manage the keystore by using management commands as explained, e.g, [here](https://wildfly-security.github.io/wildfly-elytron/blog/wildfly-encrypted-expressions/), without upgrading the WildFly version.